# Treatment of mostly blank columns using readr::spec_csv

Tags: r, readr

I'm reading a lot of sparse data where 90%+ of many character columns are blank or a single space. Using readr::read_csv it will guess these columns as logical if the first 1000 rows have no data (by design as per https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/662).

Increasing guess_max isn't practical for 1M+ rows and if I don't specify the columns the guessing of col_logical generates parsing failures when rows with character data are found, so I've been using readr::spec_csv and manually editing the spec one column at a time using:

```
colSpec$cols[['colName']] <- col_character()
```

Which is fine if there are not too many columns. For very wide data I'd like a more general form that can select all logical cols in the spec and change them, but I can't find the right syntax.
This doesn't work:

```
library(readr)
cs <- readr::spec_csv("colChar, colBlank, colNum, colSpace, colNA\n
                      a,,1, ,NA\n
                      NA,,2, ,NA")

cs
#> cols(
#>   colChar = col_character(),
#>   colBlank = col_logical(),
#>   colNum = col_double(),
#>   colSpace = col_logical(),
#>   colNA = col_logical()
#> )
cs[cs$cols == col_logical()] <- list(col_character())
cs
#> cols(
#>   colChar = col_character(),
#>   colBlank = col_logical(),
#>   colNum = col_double(),
#>   colSpace = col_logical(),
#>   colNA = col_logical()
#> )
```

Comment: I am not sure if I completely get the question but why don't you read everything as character in first place?

Comment: Because a lot of columns are numeric or date. spec_csv does a good job with most of the columns, just not the sparse ones. I could loop through the spec and change the logical to character, but I'm assuming there's single-line-of-code way to change all of them together.